# Splitting Dates in a Dataframe into 2 separate Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, datetime

I have a dataframe where two of the columns `Start` and `End` are lists of dates. What I would like to do is create two separate dataframes where, for the first dataframe, the first value in the `Start` column matches the value in the `End` column, while for the second dataframe the second value in the `Start` column also matches the value in the `End` column.

Basically, if there are two values in the `Start` column, then as long as the date in the `End` column is after the first date and before the second date (as given in row BBB in the examples below), then I want to put these values into two separate dataframes. Additionally, even if there's no date in the `End` column (as in row EEE in the examples below) then I still want to split it. Finally, if either or both the `Start` and `End` columns are empty, then they are kept in both dataframes.

As an example, for the dataframe below:

```
Name           Start                         End
AAA           2017-09-13            
BBB     2021-11-20, 2022-06-04         2022-04-07
CCC                                    2022-09-29
DDD 
EEE     2021-04-28, 2022-06-14
```

I am trying to get the first dataframe to look like this:

```
Name        Start               End
AAA        2017-09-13           
BBB        2021-11-20          2022-04-07
CCC                            2022-09-29
DDD 
EEE        2021-04-28
```

and the second dataframe to look like this:

```
Name        Start               End
AAA         2016-09-13          
BBB         2022-06-04         2022-04-07
CCC                            2022-09-29
DDD 
EEE         2022-06-14
```

If the dates in the `Start` and `End` columns weren't in lists, it would be slightly easier, but as of now I'm finding it difficult to think of a computationally fast way of doing this, so any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: you can query columns with lists, e.g. to selet the first item of every row: `df['list_column_name'].str[0]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
tmp_df = df.assign(Start=df['Start'].str.split(',')).explode('Start')

df1 = tmp_df.groupby(level=0).first()
df2 = tmp_df.groupby(level=0).last()
```

*NB. if you already have lists, you can skip the `.assign(Start=df['Start'].str.split(','))`.*

output:

```
# df1
  Name       Start         End
0  AAA  2017-09-13        None
1  BBB  2021-11-20  2022-04-07
2  CCC        None  2022-09-29
3  DDD        None        None
4  EEE  2021-04-28        None

# df2
  Name        Start         End
0  AAA   2017-09-13        None
1  BBB   2022-06-04  2022-04-07
2  CCC         None  2022-09-29
3  DDD         None        None
4  EEE   2022-06-14        None
```

Comment: that is really a beautiful solution

Comment: This is perfect, and it's so simple and easy to understand, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What i would do is to create two different columns based on the dates you have and right after that you can create the dfs you need. To do so, I would define two different functions to be applied on a vectorized with map for each case like this:

```
def first(date) -> str:
return str(date).split(", ")[0]

def second(date:str) -> str:
    return str(date).split(", ")[1]

df["first_date"] = df["start"].apply(first)
df["second_date"] = df["start"].apply(second)
```

Take into account that you should manage now the empty string but as a first approach to your problem it should give you some light.