# Splitting Dates in 2 columns in a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

This question is actually very similar to my previous one (given here: [Splitting Dates in a Dataframe into 2 separate Dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74221572/splitting-dates-in-a-dataframe-into-2-separate-dataframes)), but somewhat more complex, so after trying it for more than an hour I though I should ask.

I have a dataframe where two of the columns `Start` and `End` are lists of dates. What I would like to do is create a new dataframe where the `Start` date matches with the closest `End` date, and for each matching pair to create a new line in the outputted dataframe

Basically, if there are two values in the `Start` column, then as long as the date in the `End` column is after the first date and before the second date (as given in row BBB in the examples below), then I want to keep these values the outputted dataframe. Additionally, even if there's no date in the `End` column (as in row EEE in the examples below) then I still want to split it. And if either or both the `Start` and `End` columns are empty, then they are kept in the dataframe.

As an example, for the dataframe below:

```
Name               Start                               End
AAA               2017-09-13    
BBB         2021-11-20, 2022-06-04                 2022-04-07
CCC                                                2022-09-29
DDD 
EEE        2021-04-28, 2022-06-14
FFF        2021-06-25, 2022-06-19                2022-03-18, 2024-07-22
GGG      2020-10-23,2021-06-10, 2022-03-02       2021-03-06, 2022-01-04, 2024-08-15
```

and the final dataframe to look like this:

```
Name        Start                    End
AAA         2016-09-13          
BBB         2022-06-04             2022-04-07
CCC                                2022-09-29
DDD 
EEE         2022-06-14
FFF         2021-06-25             2022-03-18
FFF         2022-06-19             2024-07-22
GGG         2020-10-23             2021-03-06
GGG         2021-06-10             2022-01-04
GGG         2022-03-02             2024-08-15
```

I tried to modify the code as given in the link above, but I was unable to get the output I wanted (I'm quite new to Python unfortunately...). So any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually very different from your other question, and not so straightforward.

I would use a [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html), with a little trick of temporarily replacing the NaN values of End with a dummy date (here I used '1970-01-01'):

```
# pre-process the dataframe to split the strings into lists
df2 = df.set_index('Name').apply(lambda s: s.str.split(',\s*'))

out = (pd.merge_asof(
              # explode End and fill NaN with 0 to get 1970-01-01
              pd.to_datetime(df2['End'].explode().fillna(0))
                .sort_values().reset_index(),
              pd.to_datetime(df2['Start'].explode().dropna())
                .sort_values().reset_index(),
              by='Name', left_on='End', right_on='Start',
              direction='nearest'
             )
         .sort_values(by='Name')
         [['Name', 'Start', 'End']]
         .assign(End=lambda d: d['End'].mask(d['End'].eq('1970-01-01')))
      )
```

output:

```
  Name      Start        End
0  AAA 2017-09-13        NaT
7  BBB 2022-06-04 2022-04-07
1  CCC 2022-09-29        NaT
2  DDD        NaT        NaT
3  EEE 2021-04-28        NaT
6  FFF 2022-06-19 2022-03-18
8  FFF 2022-06-19 2024-07-22
4  GGG 2021-06-10 2021-03-06
5  GGG 2022-03-02 2022-01-04
9  GGG 2022-03-02 2024-08-15
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the 2nd time you've helped me! Tomorrow I'll buy you a coffee as per your profile page, you've been a big help for me!